# pgfplots with nodes near coords fails for some symbolic coords

Tags: pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

I have made a plot with pgfplots where the `symbolic coords` contain special characters input via `\texttt`. When I enable `nodes near coords`, LaTeX chokes on these special characters.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\hspace{-0.4cm}
% example derived from §4.5.4 ("Bar Plots") of the pgfplots reference
\begin{axis}[
  height=3cm,
  width=6.8cm,
  xbar,
  symbolic y coords={\texttt{N}, B},
  %nodes near coords,   % <--- uncomment for failure
  ytick=data,
  ytick style={draw=none},
  ymin={[normalized]-0.75},
  ymax={[normalized]2.75},
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {
    (4.1,\texttt{N})
    (5.5,B)
  };
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When uncommenting `nodes near coords`:

```
! Argument of \XC@definec@lor has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.30 \end{axis}

...
```

The same happens with `\mathbb` instead of `\texttt`.

Do you have any idea how to make `nodes near coords` work correctly in my case?

Comment: Better use `symbolic y coords={N, B}, yticklabels={\texttt{N}, B}` and then place the coordinate at `(4.1,N)`. This is far less error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to style the tick labels, I would suggest using the option `yticklabels` to define the labels of the y axis. Also, I would probably just use numeric coordinates to position the data on the y axis which is in general easier to handle.

Maybe also consider using `enlarge y limits={0.75}` to increase the spacing above and below the y axis rather than changing `ymin` and `ymax`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\hspace{-0.4cm}
% example derived from §4.5.4 ("Bar Plots") of the pgfplots reference
\begin{axis}[
  height=3cm,
  width=6.8cm,
  xbar,
%  symbolic y coords={N, B}, 
  yticklabels={\texttt{N}, B},
  nodes near coords,          % <--- uncomment for success
  ytick=data,
  ytick style={draw=none},
  enlarge y limits={0.75},
%  ymin={[normalized]-0.75},
%  ymax={[normalized]2.75},
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {
    (4.1,1)
    (5.5,2)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want to use symbolic coordinates, you can add the option `symbolic y coords={N, B}` (that is: just use regular strings, no macros) and place the coordiates at `(4.1,N)` and `(5.5,B)`. Again, you can format the labels with `yticklabels={\texttt{N}, B}`. Using macros as coordinates is very likely to result in errors.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I especially like your approach of using `yticklabels` together with `symbolic y coords`, that is definitively much cleaner than using macros as coordinates, while still allowing me to have proper data labels in my CSV tables.